# Combining SailsJS and EmberJS (routing)

Tags: node.js, ember.js, sails.js, javascriptmvc

I've been using SailsJS for a while now and find it a perfect REST API solution. I'm currently building an app for both Web & Mobile (native) so I need the REST part of SailsJS. I want to build a frontend for my API right now, and I found EmberJS which looks like a promising framework. I've a question about combining those two, they both have their own Routing system, and SailsJS seems to overrule Ember's one.

My guesses would be:

1. The most easy approach looks like building Sails in a subdirectory
   eg. /api/ but I think that's not the nicest way to get this fixed.
2. I could choose one framework for routing and let the other delegating it's routes. For example passing parameters from SailsJS through EmberJS

How can I use those together correctly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Think of your backand as something you can't control, like a 3rd party API. The reason is that the optimal routing for a user may differ greatly from what's considered to be good API semantics. It's also not easy to share the route declarations, but it's not a good practice anyway.

My advice:

- Use [ember-cli](https://github.com/stefanpenner/ember-cli) to build the frontend. It's a great tool, you'll enjoy it a lot.
- Build your Sails-based API in a different repository, using the `/api` namespace for your API endpoints.
- Try to follow the [JSON API standard](http://jsonapi.org) as closely as possible. That'll make easier to connect your backend & frontend, as most data libraries (Ember Data for eg.) tries to adhere those standards as well.
- Watch Luke Melia's [excellent guide](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QZVYP3cPcWQ) on lighning fast deployment. It'll be the same concept for you but in Sails intead of Ruby/Rails.

All in all, I think if you'll have a great dev experience if you do roughly what I've outlined above. Happy coding!

Comment: Hi thanks for answering, one more little question, does a different repository also mean you would deploy it on a different server?

Comment: Not necessarily, it's your call to serve the static assets from eg. S3 (recommended) or straight from your Sails app. The index.html should be served from Sails, though. Watch the video, it'll explain it to you in detail!